# /bin/bash warning shell level (1000) too high resetting to 1 in linux

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to run a bash script

```
./my_new_whois.sh my_who_is_yahoo_ mnt.txt persons.txt
```

Its giving me an error

```
/bin/bash warning shell level (1000) too high resetting to 1
```

Can anyone please let me know how do I run my bash script so it can sort my .txt file?

Comment: Your `./my_new_whois.sh` is probably calling itself recursively. That's probably not intended -- your script works like a fork bomb.

Comment: For sorting `.txt` files, I recommend `sort(1)`.

Comment: You can't. The script is calling itself recursively, or so it appears. To get some help to resolve it, please provide the script and a sample of the input data that still exhibit the same symptoms.